# Highcharts series not updating when hidden with current live time

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

i am getting problem here is, when the highchart series is hidden the points not updating with its current live time but when it is not hidden(shown) it is updating data with its current live time currectly.

how can i updates the points with its current time when the series is hidden.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H64Ky.png

please open the link and see the purple color line was hidden before and then i shown after some interval of time as you can see the purple color line points is not till at the end.

when i inspect element from the browser the hidden series was not updating.

Any idea???

```
 $(document).on('click', '.SpeedCheckbox', function () {
 var chart = $('#SpeedGraph').highcharts();
 var series = chart.get(id);
if (series.visible) {
    series.hide();
 } else {
     series.show();
 }
 });

  function addpoints(){
   for (var key in lineview.Signals) {
        var signal = lineview.Signals[key];
  var series = chart.get(signal.MachineId);
                y = parseInt(signal.LatestValue);
                var speedTrendData = series.data;
                var lastTime = speedTrendData[speedTrendData.length - 1].x;
                var x = new Date(lastTime + PageVariables.GraphRefreshRate()).getTime();
                series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
  }
setInterval("addpoints()", 1000);
```

Comment: I run simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7jbqqtkn/ and when serie is hidden, points are added. You can observe that when you show serie after couple of seconds. Let me know if works for you, properly.

Comment: well its working now what i did is replace the var x value with the current time.